# Upgrading Ubuntu 21.04 to Ubuntu 21.10

Tags: 21.10

Limited disk space, so ....
How much free disk space is required (on a Ubuntu 21.04 machine) to upgrade to Ubuntu 21.10?   The system requirements that I see are only for a fresh install rather than what is necessary to fit the manipulation files above existing Ubuntu 21.04 files.

Comment: How much do you currently have? Please share output of `df -h`.

Comment: You may want to do a clean install so that you can allocate more space to the new installation.

Comment: or resize existing partitions.

Comment: When you run `do-release-upgrade`, the upgrader will calculate how much free space is needed. If you are short, it will tell you exactly how much.